# How to decode and read unity udp packets?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, security, ipa

I am capturing the udp traffic of my mobile device to understand how the unity messages are sent, with what format, etc.

Currently I am not being able to even read them, I only see their hexadecimal value and if I want to transform it into ascii it does not make any sense. Only sometimes do you see a meaningful value like my username.

As I was able to speak with the developers of the game, unity sends by udp packages values ​​such as the position, the speed with which the character moves, the strength of the shots etc. But I need to be able to see those values ​​and now I can't figure out how.

[image: Wireshark capturing udp packets]

Most of the packets are short and look like this:
Hexa: `450000282e4c40002711d6cb12c07b11c0a80034b55aeeff00146cac000185649a8b002080000000`
Ascii: `E(.L@'ÖËÀ{À¨4µZîÿl¬d`

The biggest one with some information are similar to this:
Hexa:`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`

Ascii: `` EöÐp@,¿×À¨4ÿ âÔzLÏ ÀÿËÆc`Møpùe4¨PvLFAµÍÌÍÂ ×#=ÍÌÂ4ÍÌÍÂ ×#=ÍÌÂ´B´B´Bú?Â6îCCID¤.ð½gÄèñhë V0ÉmAÖBz½Ò?åøéÉµB1TesttesttestQKáûdÞõU$û¯\ðT{lÕ1B$÷éR#ÀÛ ×r¢Ä©©h¦i£e   ý0¶SÆÌT¹+: lÕ1B$÷éR#ÀÛ ×r¢Ä©©h¦i£e  ý0¶SÆÌT¹+: ô5?ò5?6 & ``

Where Testtesttest is my Username

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds like trying to hack a game and if the game writers don’t want to share how they do that that’s their choice and also beyond the scope of an SO question

Comment: I understand but it's totally the opposite. I'm part of the security team of one of the biggest mobile games company in Brasil. We are trying to understand how unity encode udp packets to build a proxy to perform our internal security assessments. 

Regards